# list of apps for stack exchange

Tags: discussion, stackapps

If I go to my profile page,there is a link next to flar called apps. It provides a valuable way to revoke permission to various apps that use my information from stack exchange. It currently lists winterbash and desktop notifications. Is there a list of all apps or popular apps that I could use?

Comment: I don't think Stack Exchange maintains a complete list of all apps that use access tokens from the network. Most of them will probably be linked somewhere here on Meta though. I know of [Stinking Badges](http://agent86ix.github.io/stackapps/badge/).

Comment: [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)?

Comment: @TimStone, I saw It, but today most of the questions were questions. there were a couple announcements, but I didn't find any lists of popular apps, much less all apps.

Comment: @animuson Stinking Badges is cool.